# Strange error on click on Button (Swift Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a newest Swift programmer. I'm building a simple app to iOS system.
I have a strange error when I try to click on one button of my application.

This is the first View:

[image]

If I try yo click on "Kit Button", I have this error but I don't know I can I fix it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You question doesn't tell anything about your problem. You should past exception error.

Comment: @birc astri please show code not images.

Comment: add the break point and check once

Comment: check your @IBOutlets of the button

Comment: I need to see your `ViewController` class to know what's wrong

Comment: Add your view controller's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug by following steps:

1. Go to breakpoint navigator
2. Click on '+' button in bottom left
3. Click on exception breakpoint
4. Select All exceptions

Run application again with debug mode active , you can see on which line code breaks.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I have activate Output View and I have see that there isn't a reference of an ImageView of my TableViewCell (Custom), so I have renamed it and the works. Thanks you very much